# vim c++ template writing

Tags: c++, qt, vim, qt-creator

Vim has templates and idioms programming and other similar stuff.
For example, the [c.vim : C/C++ IDE](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213) plugin for vim provides this programming support.
QtCreator has FakeVim.

How can I adjust FakeVim to use those things?

Comment: Have you thought about why it is named "fake" vim?

Comment: Why do you still use vim instead of normal IDE? Is this any problem with your pc and you are working on remote one?

Comment: @AlexTheo: Why do you compare Vim to an IDE ? Vim is just a text editor, and a pretty good one at that. Now a good IDE should be able to use whatever text editor the user desires :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. FakeVim is not a proper vim, if I understood it correctly, but just an implementation of some of the vim commands inside QtCreator. That means that it will behave in a manner similar to vim only for those features that they have implemented.

Comment: Does QtCreator has any template facilities?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I have only used QtCreator for a few days some months ago, and I used it mainly to navigate through code. I use vim for actual coding.

Comment: How do you compile your code? How do you maintain your projects?

Comment: @itun: It depends on the project. To compile Makefile/CMake/QMake in the least cases, with the projects stored in some CM (subversion/ClearCase/git).

Comment: @itun ... the terminal? vi? Depends. You can call `make` from within `vi` and the editor will parse the errors and jump right to the line, but I most often call `make` directly from the terminal (note that CMake generates Makefiles)

Comment: Is it appropriate for you every time you close the terminal or restart system or something else to write commands in terminal?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7214/discussion-between-itun-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)